# If statments are ignored by code after an input in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

I am new to Python and am learning about the `time` module. I was messing around with the module trying to write a program that outputs either UTC or Local time depending on the user's input, however when I run the program `newtime = input("Would you like to see Local or UTC time? ")` executes, but not the if statements.

```
import time

newtime = input("Would you like to see Local or UTC time? ")
#newtime stores user input
if newtime.lower == "utc":
    #If newtime lowercase equals to utc this if line will run
    print(time.strftime("The current time and date in UTC is: %c ", time.gmtime()))
    #strftime formats the struct_time from gmtime() into something more readable
elif newtime.lower == "local":
    #If newtime lowercase equals to local this elif line will run
    print(time.strftime("The current time and date in local is: %c", time.localtime()))
    #strftime formats the struct_time from localtime() into something more readable
else:
    print("Input not recognized, please type 'Local' or 'UTC'")
    #If neither local or utc are inputed this prints
```

I thought the problem might be `newtime` but that wasn't it. I originally had `newtime = input("Would you like to see Local or UTC time? ").lower` because I'm new to programming but that wasn't it either.

Comment: You aren't calling the function. `if newtime.lower() == ...`

Comment: `.lower` is a *method* of string objects, not a property.  You have to write `newtime.lower()` to actually call the method.  Currently, you're comparing the method itself - it's never going to be equal to `"utc"` or any of the other strings, because it is not itself a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the functions in your if statements:

```py
newtime = input("Would you like to see Local or UTC time? ")

if newtime.lower() == "utc":
    ...
elif newtime.lower() == "local":
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Otherwise you are just doing:

```py
if str.lower == 'utc':
    ...
```

Which will always be `False` because a function is never equal to a string